# How to obtain authtoken for request via powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, http, httpwebrequest

I need to add an authorization token to a request I'm making via powershell. In c#, I can get the token like this:

```
private static string GetAccessToken()
    {
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(((MyApp)Application.Current).AuthorityAddress);
        Task<AuthenticationResult> resultTask = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
            (myAuthServerAddress,
            clientId,
            redirectUri,
            new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, false));

        resultTask.Wait();
        return resultTask.Result.AccessToken;
    }
```

How would I do this in powershell? I need to get that token to add as a header:

```
Authorization: Bearer blahblahblahtokenblahblah
```

Answer (score 1):

Try run the following code in PowerShell:

```
function Get-AzureRmCachedAccessToken()
{
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

  if(-not (Get-Module AzureRm.Profile)) {
    Import-Module AzureRm.Profile
  }
  $azureRmProfileModuleVersion = (Get-Module AzureRm.Profile).Version
  # refactoring performed in AzureRm.Profile v3.0 or later
  if($azureRmProfileModuleVersion.Major -ge 3) {
    $azureRmProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
    if(-not $azureRmProfile.Accounts.Count) {
      Write-Error "Ensure you have logged in before calling this function."    
    }
  } else {
    # AzureRm.Profile < v3.0
    $azureRmProfile = [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Common.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile
    if(-not $azureRmProfile.Context.Account.Count) {
      Write-Error "Ensure you have logged in before calling this function."    
    }
  }

  $currentAzureContext = Get-AzureRmContext
  $profileClient = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient($azureRmProfile)
  Write-Debug ("Getting access token for tenant" + $currentAzureContext.Subscription.TenantId)
  $token = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($currentAzureContext.Subscription.TenantId)
  $token.AccessToken
}

Get-AzureRmCachedAccessToken
```

From: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Easily-obtain-AccessToken-3ba6e593

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
$bearerAuthValue = "Bearer {token}"

$headers = @{ Authorization = $bearerAuthValue }
```

Invoke Web Request like this

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://api.google.com/user" -Headers $headers
```

You can find further info here https://foxdeploy.com/2015/11/02/using-powershell-and-oauth/

Comment: How do I get the token though?

Comment: i think you have to call authenticate API with basic token and get the access token from the response of that call and use it to make further calls...